# Upload a csv with fileInput, Filter its data with dateInput and use the results in a Leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny

I Want to upload a file to my shiny app, them i want to filter this file using dateInput and add the result to a Leaflet map, Nevertheless, I can't find an example and all my tries did not work. It says the file is not subsetable. I would greatly appreciate any help!

I believe the problem is in the serve section. I need to upload a CSV file and then, somehow I must apply a date filter to this CSV I uploaded. Then, this filtered data will go into Leaflet.

Here is my code:

...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leaflet.extras)

library(rgdal)
library(DT)



ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        inputId = "filedata",
        label = "Upload data. Choose csv file",
        accept = c(".csv")
      ),

      checkboxInput(
        inputId = "positive",
        label = "Positive",
        value = FALSE
      ),
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = "class_positive",
        label = "class",
        value = FALSE
      ),
      dateInput(inputId = "date",
                label="Insira a Data",
                value = NULL, 
                min=Sys.Date()-20,
                max = Sys.Date()+20, 
                textOutput("seldate"), 
                format = "yyyy-mm-dd"
      ),

      p("Made with", a("Shiny",
                       href = "http://shiny.rstudio.com"
      ), "."),
      img(
        src = "imageShiny.png",
        width = "70px", height = "70px"
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(outputId = "map"),
      leafletOutput("mymap", height = 500),

      DTOutput(outputId = "table")

    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {


  data <- reactive({

    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath)
  })



  output$table <- renderDT(data())

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({


    leaflet(cities) %>% 
      setView(lng = -45, lat = 22, zoom = 2) 
      addTiles() 

  })

  rawData <- eventReactive(input$filedata, {
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath)

  })



  pal <- reactive({colorNumeric(
    palette = c('gold', 'orange', 'dark orange', 'orange red', 'red', 'dark red'),
    domain = req(rawData$positive))
  })

  pal2 <- reactive({colorFactor(
    palette = c('blue', 'yellow', 'red'),
    domain = req(rawData$class_positive))
  })


  a_data <- eventReactive(input$filedata, {
    <-read.csv2(input$filedata$datapath)

  })

  observe({

    proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap", data = a_data )
    proxy %>% clearMarkers()

    if (input$positive == TRUE) {

      proxy %>% clearMarkers() %>% clearShapes()

      proxy %>% addCircles(data = a_data(), lat = ~ longitude,
                           lng = ~ latitude, weight = 1, 
                           radius = ~sqrt(positive)*25000, 
                           popup = ~Place, 
                           label = ~Place, 
                           color = ~pal, fillOpacity = 0.5) 
    }
    else {
      proxy %>%  clearMarkers() %>% clearControls() %>%  clearMarkerClusters() %>% clearShapes()

    }
  })


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can understand what is your problem but I created a simplified example that I hope is on point: my takeaway is that you cannot filter a reactive data object by date. Would be great if you had provided a reproducible example. 
Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

First I created a small csv file with two columns: Date , Value. We will have something to read. The file contains dates from 1/1/2020 up to today and random numbers.

Also, I use package `DT` as I find that gives more reliable results compared to the `shiny:datatable` functions.

The code below allows me to read an csv files, make sure the Date column is properly formatted and make it available as a reactive object.
In the server code I read a date and filter the reactive object such that only observations with a date larger than the selected date are retained. `DT:renderDataTable` subsequently renders the data table.
Is this what you were after?

`ui.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
  titlePanel("demo code"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        inputId = "filedata",
        label = "Upload data. Choose csv file",
        accept = c(".csv")
      ),
      dateInput(inputId = "date",
                label="Insert a Date",
                value = NULL, 
                min = as.Date("2020/01/01"),
                max = Sys.Date()+20, 
                textOutput("seldate"), 
                format = "yyyy-mm-dd"
      )
    ),
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput('table')
  )
 )
)
)
```

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$date, {
    date <- input$date
    #browser()
    data_filtered <- data() %>%
      filter(Date > date)
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data_filtered,
                                    options = list(pageLength = 5))

  })

}
)
```

And here is a screenshot to see how this simple shiny app looks like.

[image]

Comment: i'm afraid it is not quite what  i need... in your code the date filters the table right?

Comment: actually i need to filter the data...and then, the filtered data must go into a leaflet map...
actually I given up to do this dynamically...i removed the FileInput and I'm reading a file instead of letting the user to chose

Comment: Not really, the filter is applied to the reactive object data(). After that it is passed to the datatable rendering function. You can pass it to leaflet in your case.
This is easy to do dynamically, as my example shows. As you change the date in the widget, the data is filtered accordingly.

data_filtered is a reactive object I assume. You call it once as a reactive object as data_filtered() and later as a non-reactive object as data_filtered (without the parenthesis). 
If I do that my app crashes immediately with this error message:

`Warning: Error in <-: object is not a matrix`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your quick response and i'm sorry for not providing a working examples, but basically, any file with a date and any other column will do.

In my specific case, reading the data and putting into a table was not the problem. My problem is to filter by date and update the map.

When I use "data" (raw data inserted with fileInput) the map works...

when I use data_filteres (that is the data with a specific date filter) then everything crashes when I mark the checkbox named "positive"

And other interesting thing, when I read a csv file (without the fileInput but with regular code like read.csv), the date filter worked the way I did before. Nevertheless, I needed that the map let the user insert his data and dynamically filter by date or by any other attribute... i saw dozens of examples in forums but neither of them seem to deal with this specific problem. Is this really impossible to make? I think there is a work around...maybe creating a button to read a script and generate a csv already filtered by date... but this solution won't be as good... i much appreciate any help

The real issue is this part of the code here:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(data_filtered) %>% 
      setView(lng = -45, lat = 22, zoom = 2)  %>% #setting the view over ~ center of Brazil
      addTiles() 

  })



  observe({

    proxy <- leafletProxy("mymap", data = data_filtered )
    proxy %>% clearMarkers()

    if (input$positive == TRUE) {

      proxy %>% clearMarkers() %>% clearShapes()


      proxy %>% addCircles(data = data_filtered(), lat = ~ longitude,
                           lng = ~ latitude, weight = 1, 
                           radius = ~sqrt(positive)*25000, 
                           popup = ~Place, 
                           label = ~Place, 
                           color = ~pal, fillOpacity = 0.5) 
    }
    else {
      proxy %>%  clearMarkers() %>% clearControls() %>%  clearMarkerClusters() %>% clearShapes()

    }
  })
```

Comment: when i try  as your code shows it says that the variable is not subsetable